# Value Dependent on Other Field (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have created a table in ms access for calculating shipment charges.

There are 5 fields
1) Weight
2) No_of_pieces
3) Chargeable type (combo box)
4) Rate
5) Total_Price

I have a combo box namely chargeable type if user select chargeable type to A then I want that total price will be calculated by this formula Weight*Rate
And if user select chargeable type to B total price should be calculated by this formula No_of_pieces * Rate.

How to do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression in textbox:

`=[Rate] * IIf([chargeable type]="A", [Weight], [No_of_pieces])`

Comment: Thanks alot man can we use multiple iif statements in a single field ??

Comment: Certainly. Or maybe Switch or Choose functions would be simpler.